# Two phase simplex when constraint is the same as minimize function

Tags: linear-programming, two-phase-simplex

Consider the following linear program:

> Maximize $Z = x - y$ where $-x+y\ge 1$ and $x\ge 0, y\ge 0$

Add surplus and artificial variables to the constraint: $-x+y-s+a=1$

For phase 1 maximize $W = -a = -x+y-s-1$. The starting tableau is

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc|c}
&x&y&s&a&b\\
\hline
a&-1&1&-1&1&1\\
\hline
W&-1&1&-1&0&1
\end{array}
$$

The only positive element in in column 2, so $y$ is the entering variable. The only constraint row is row 1, $a$ is the leaving variable. Pivot around (1,2) to get

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc|c}
&x&y&s&a&b\\
\hline
y&-1&1&-1&1&1\\
\hline
W&0&0&0&-1&0
\end{array}
$$

$W = 0$ is the maximum, phase 1 is done. Remove the artificial column and initialize the last row for phase 2, maximize $Z = x-y$:

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc|c}
&x&y&s&b\\
\hline
y&-1&1&-1&1\\
\hline
Z&-1&1&0&0
\end{array}
$$

The only positive entry in the last row is in column 2, the only row is row 1: pivot around (1,2) to get

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc|c}
&x&y&s&b\\
\hline
y&-1&1&-1&1\\
\hline
Z&0&0&1&-1
\end{array}
$$

Now the only positive objective entry is in column 2, but there are no positive entries in that column to pivot around! According to Wikipedia this means that the linear program is unbounded. Looking at this problem geometrically:

[image]

It is clear that the problem isn't "really" unbounded: $Z$ can at most be $-1$. I assume the Simplex algorthm breaks down because it doesn't realize that in order to increase $x$ $y$ must also be increased, keeping $Z$ at the same value. Is there a way to change the algorithm so it does not break down in this case, and simply stops at the last tableau?

Comment: Is $x,y\geq 0$, the non-negativity condition?

Comment: @callculus Yes, I'll edit the image to clarify.

Comment: Ok. Please edit the problem as well. Otherwise it is confusing.

Comment: @callculus Yup, done that as well.

Comment: Great. At the last tableau why you don´t insert the negative coefficients of the objective function? Isn´t the rule: max problem$\rightarrow$negative coefficients of the objective function in the tableau.

Comment: @callculus You're right, dumb mistake. I fixed that, but unfortunately the problem remains.

Comment: Isn´t the solution just $(x^*,y^*)=(0,1)$? I read off the result from your final tableau.

Comment: Right, _I_ know that because this is a simple example, but how would the Simplex algorithm know to stop at the last tableau?

Comment: If all coefficients (in the table) of the objective function are non-negative.

Comment: @callculus It's the other way around, right? You keep pivoting around columns with a positive objective coefficient until there are only non-positive coefficients left, and then your solution is optimal.

Comment: No the other way round. It´s as I said.

Comment: Ah so the end condition would be if they're either all negative or all non-negative we're done, otherwise continue pivoting? Because [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm#Entering_variable_selection) says "If all the entries in the objective row are less than or equal to 0 then no choice of entering variable can be made and the solution is in fact optimal."

Comment: I´m not sure to what specific problem wiki is referring. I still remain at what I have said. I have another problem. $(x,y)=(1,2)$ would also be an opitmal solution, or more general $(x,y)=(x,x+1)$ And this solution we cannot read off from the final tableau. On the other hand wolfram alpha has the only solution $(x^*,y^*)=(0,1)$ See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max+x-y,+-x%2By%3E1,+x%3E0,+y%3E0)

Comment: @callculus Well presumably you can't read the other solutions from the tableau because a tableau always represents a solution in one of the intersections, never somewhere on a line.